# selector with context throw exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

why jQuery throwing such exception when I try to select element with context. the code are following:

```
jQuery('b', "DAS<br/><br/><b>ID</b> = 02<br/><b>NAMA DAS</b> = CITARUM<br/><b>LUAS (KM2)</b> = 6644.90<br/><b>WILAYAH SUNGAI</b> = CITARUM<br/><b>KODE WS</b> = 02.06.A3<br/><b>WILAYAH ADMINISTRASI</b> = JAWA BARAT<br/><b>WILAYAH KERJA</b> = BBWS CITARUM");
```

it's keep throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: DAS<br/>...
```

Comment: We'll need your HTML code to try and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context):

> context
>   Type: Element or jQuery
>   A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

The issue is that you can't create a jQuery element with your string, because it's not a valid html.

Again [from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2):

> jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )
>   html
>   Type: htmlString
>   A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, not XML.

You can wrap your content with `div` element, and then you can use jquery to extract data from that element.

```js
let html = "<div>DAS<br/><br/><b>ID</b> = 02<br/><b>NAMA DAS</b> = CITARUM<br/><b>LUAS (KM2)</b> = 6644.90<br/><b>WILAYAH SUNGAI</b> = CITARUM<br/><b>KODE WS</b> = 02.06.A3<br/><b>WILAYAH ADMINISTRASI</b> = JAWA BARAT<br/><b>WILAYAH KERJA</b> = BBWS CITARUM</div>";
let elements = jQuery('b', jQuery(html));
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In case you can't "touch" the string - you can just add the wrap element with a simple string concat:

```js
let content = "DAS<br/><br/><b>ID</b> = 02<br/><b>NAMA DAS</b> = CITARUM<br/><b>LUAS (KM2)</b> = 6644.90<br/><b>WILAYAH SUNGAI</b> = CITARUM<br/><b>KODE WS</b> = 02.06.A3<br/><b>WILAYAH ADMINISTRASI</b> = JAWA BARAT<br/><b>WILAYAH KERJA</b> = BBWS CITARUM";
let html = "<div>" + content + "</div>";
let elements = jQuery('b', jQuery(html));
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So the answer is "Because *context* must be either an Element, a Document or a jQuery object, and that a String is neither of these."

Comment: oh man, I was trying to wrap the string in a complete html document ie. `<!DOCTYPE html><html>...` but the selector didn't work, zero length return. but a simple `div` wrapping make it work perfectly..can you explain why my solution doesnt work? anyway thank you very much.

Comment: @DarielPratama you should basically wrap it with `<!doctype html><html><div>` (or event better - `html->body->div`).